# delete SMS from SMStable in android

Tags: java, android, sms

I am currently trying to delete a SMS from the SMS table from android.
I used this to delete the SMS but there are errors.
Is this the correct syntax?
the messageID is the id of the message to be deleted.

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox/" + messageID);

 getContentResolver().delete(uriSMSURI, null, null);
```

Comment: check permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: also, the error says java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for deleteing an sms you must add these permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"> </ uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"> </ uses-permission>
```

URI's for reading and deleting sms:

```
//Available Uri string
  String strUriInbox = "content://sms/inbox";//SMS_INBOX:1
  String strUriFailed = "content://sms/failed";//SMS_FAILED:2
  String strUriQueued = "content://sms/queued";//SMS_QUEUED:3
  String strUriSent = "content://sms/sent";//SMS_SENT:4
  String strUriDraft = "content://sms/draft";//SMS_DRAFT:5
  String strUriOutbox = "content://sms/outbox";//SMS_OUTBOX:6
  String strUriUndelivered = "content://sms/undelivered";//SMS_UNDELIVERED
  String strUriAll = "content://sms/all";//SMS_ALL
  String strUriConversations = "content://sms/conversations";//you can delete one conversation by thread_id
  String strUriAll = "content://sms"//you can delete one message by _id
```

Comment: I just needed to change content://sms/inbox/ with content://sms/