# Im trying to call a private class from button event and i get java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: android

The following is my code: Basically i am calling progress class to run it from a button listener and i get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

is thiere a way to run this progress class from a button or a menu ?

```
public class ProgressDialogeActivity extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog dialog;
int count = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // running from main activity
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    dialog.setMessage("Deleteng Contacts ...");
    dialog.setMax(50);
    // dialog.show();
    // dialog.setProgress(40);
    Object Maxmssg = checkhowmanysms();
    // dialog.setMax((Integer) Maxmssg);

    Button deletesms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    deletesms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress prog = new progress();
            prog.start();

        }
    });

}

public class progress extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMessage("Deleteng Contacts ...");
        int size = checkhowmanysms();
        Object Maxmssg = checkhowmanysms();
        dialog.setMax((Integer) Maxmssg);
        dialog.show();

        Uri inboxUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        Cursor item = getContentResolver().query(inboxUri, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (item.moveToNext()) {
            count++;
            dialog.setProgress(count);

            // Delete the SMS
            String pid = item.getString(0); // Get id;
            String uri = "content://sms";
            getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(uri), null, null);

        }
        dialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you add the correct permissions?

[permission][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616476/delete-sms-from-smstable-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify the UI from a background thread, you are not allowed to do this, instead, use [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (for the UI modification part).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to change the UI from a non-UI thread. The solution for this is to either use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), and one of the `post()` methods, or if you can call the `Activity`s [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)-method